# How do I collect all agreements related to a plan under the rest paypal api?

Tags: rest, paypal

I went through the api calls under billing plans and agreements:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#retrieve-an-agreement

I am looking for a way to be able to retrieve all the billing agreement id's from the different plans that I have created. Any ideas?

Thanks for the help!